# Bounds for multi-dimensional Kloosterman Sums

Tags: number-theory, characters

I'm looking for a general bound (in terms of $p$) for the Kloosterman sum, working in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$,

$$\sum\limits_{x_{1} \dots \ x_{n} = a} \psi(x_{1} + \dots + x_{n})$$ for $\psi$ a nontrivial additive character.

These are well studied, and I've found papers that discuss them which give bounds, but unfortunately I can't seem to find a single agreed upon answer and indeed in what I've found there appears to be contradictory information.

Does someone know what the "correct" bound is, and/or know of a good source?

Comment: In your sum, you should specify that $\psi$ is a *nontrivial* character, and the sum should be over $x_i$'s with product equal to $a$. As you write the sum, it's just over a list: $x_1,\cdots,x_n = a$. The commas should not be there.  It would be nice if you would tell us what papers and bounds you have found, and in what sense you consider the information in them to be contradictory.

Comment: See pp.308-309 of http://www.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/ik-ant-exp-sums.pdf, which has reference to work of Deligne on bounds for multiple Kloosterman sums.

Comment: Deligne's bound is also mentioned on p. 254 of Lidl and Niederreiter's Finite Fields (Camb. Univ. Press edition).